# How to bin values in Fortran

Tags: arrays, sorting, fortran, gfortran, binning

I am trying to bin `n` particles by mass, where each particle has an associated x,y,z position stored in `xyzh(1,n)`, `xyzh(2,n)`, `xyzh(3,n)` respectively and each particle also has an equal mass which is stored in `particlemass`. My code looks like this:

```
  integer, intent(in) :: n,iunit
  real, intent(in)    :: particlemass
  integer,  parameter :: nbins = 500         ! number of bins 
  real,     parameter :: mmax = 1.0072       ! max mass
  integer             :: i,j
  integer             :: ibins(nbins)
  real                :: ri,mi,dm
  real                :: rbins(nbins),mass(nbins),mbins(nbins)

  !-- Initialise parameters
  rbins = 0.0
  ibins = 0
  mbins = 0.0
```

Here I am setting my bins, `dm` is the mass of each bin and `mbins` cumulatively adds the mass of each bin so the rows of `mbins` would look like 1,2,3,4 if we assume the mass in each bin is 1.

```
  !--Set bins
  dm   = mmax/float(nbins)    ! mass of each bin                                                                                                           
  do i = 1,nbins
     mbins(i) = float(i)*dm   ! cumulatively adds mass in each bin                                                                                    
  enddo
```

What I am doing here is binning my data in 500 bins (`nbins`). I'm calculating the radius of each particle `ri` and then binning these values into `rbins(nbins)`.
What I am *trying* to do is add particles to each bin and when it's mass exceeds that of a certain value, that of the mass of the first bin, i.e. `mbins(1)`, or the difference in value/mass between each consecutive `mbins`, we then move to the next bin and start adding particles there until the same criterion is satisfied.

```
  !--Binning data
  parts: do i = 1,n

  !--Calculate properties of the particle
  if (xyzh(4,i)  <  tiny(xyzh)) cycle parts         ! skip dead particles
  ri = sqrt(dot_product(xyzh(1:3,i),xyzh(1:3,i)))   ! radius of each particle
  mi = mi + particlemass

  !--Find the bin
  j = 1
  do while (mi <= mbins(1) .and. j<nbins)
     j = j + 1
  enddo
  if (j<nbins) then
     ibins(j) = ibins(j) + 1
     rbins(j) = rbins(j) + ri
  endif 
  enddo parts
```

Here I am writing my results out to a file and calculating the mass in each bin.

```
  !--Write out results                                                                                                                                     
  open(iunit,file='results.dat')
  do i = 1,nbins
     mass = ibins(i)*particlemass           ! mass in each shell
  write(iunit,*) mass(i),mbins(i),rbins(i)/ibins(i)
  enddo
  close(unit)
```

Instead of giving me equal values of mass in `mass(i)`, I am just getting zeros and my `rbins(i)/ibins(i)` gives me NaNs.
What am I doing wrong here and how would I bin these particles correctly?

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Update: only first row seems to be working, but the rest are zeros.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark no I hadn't done that...but now I'm just getting NaNs for radius other than the first row

Comment: `mi <= mbins(1)`  should that be a `j` ?

Comment: @agentp the masses (in `mass(:)`) are too big when I do it that way I think because `mbins` cumulatively adds mass from each bin before it, also it gives me NaNs for the radius

Comment: the result of that loop will be `j=1` or `j=nbins` . You may as well use an if statement, but my guess is thats not the intent.

Comment: Following what agentp said, should `do while (mi <= mbins(1) ...`  be `do while (mi <= mbins(i) ...` or `do while (mi <= mbins(j) ...` ?